# How do I view an older version of my Chrome cache

Tags: google-chrome, cache

I'm trying to access a specific version of a web page that I know I accessed from my machine earlier today. However, I've visited the page since it's changed, so my Chrome cache has updated to the new version.

The version of the cache that I'm looking for was at some point on my machine, is there a way to restore or access it?

The version I'm looking for isn't on way back machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Web Cache Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-cache-viewer/pbkloffickinnlnmefmjmjbacohecpbd) extension for Chrome.  However, depending on a variety of factors, it might have been purged and replaced with the new site.

Comment: Right, that doesn't answer my question.  I am able to view the latest cache, I am trying to access an older version.